# Is there a SymPy function that simplifies(shortens) a polynomial expression?

Tags: python, sympy, polynomials

I use SymPy to calculate Bezier curves and my output for x coordinate is

```
6.0*t**3 + 12.0*t**2*(1 - t) + 6.0*t*(t**2 - 2*t + 1)
```

while the desired output is `6*t`. If you do the math both of these outputs are the same, but one is just not in the shortest form. Any suggestion what to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using `simplify()` function:

```
>>> simplify(6.0*t**3 + 12.0*t**2*(1 - t) + 6.0*t*(t**2 - 2*t + 1))
6.0t
```

Comment: Simplify function works in cmd but the exact same line of code in Atom outputs 5.940000...

Comment: If you get `5.940000` as result, you're clearly doing something wrong.  Also note that sympy isn't very happy with floats, and prefers them to be written as whole numbers and as fractions.

Comment: I finally made it work using .item() method on a 1-D numpy array which includes the expression. I'm only working with ints but sympy change them to floats.
`>>> sp.simplify(np.dot(bern_poly, Vx).item())
6.0*t`